# solve diophantine equation $a+b+2ab=n$

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratic-residues

I need to find the samllest positive integer value of a for which $(n - a) / (1 + 2 a)$ is an integer. where n is a given natural number .

In other words solve diophantine equation for postive $a$, $b$,

$a+b+2ab=n$

To make it more specific I am only interested in the smallest value of $a$.

Since some users are confused with the problem statement I want to re-emphasize that the value of n is given or constant. You don't need to solve for all values of n, you just need to solve for one particular value of n. You can assume n to be any large integer say if $n = 1000$, then you are to solve $a+b+2ab=1000$

**My thoughts so far:**

Since we can express $b(1+2a)=n-a$

is to try out all values of $a=1 \to  \sqrt{n}$

WLOG we assume $a<b$, then $a$ is bound to be less than $\sqrt{n}$ so we reduce search space somewhat.

But its not very efficient way.

Comment: Your equation implies $2n+1=(2a+1)(2b+1)$, so the problem is equivalent to factoring $2n+1$ (specifically finding its smallest factor).

Comment: @Sil What I understand the samllest factor of $(2n+1)$ can be retrieved in $\sqrt[4]{n}$  using technique like pollard rho. Oeis is talking about factoring as well. Guys Am I on same page or do you see something better than $\sqrt[4]{n}$ ?

Comment: There are many integer factorization methods, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization . I think that general number field sieve is currently the fastest for really large integers. There must be some suitable duplicate for that on this site I suppose ...

Comment: @Sil Yes the best is $O(\sqrt[4]{n})$ as said. Point is given that we need only the smallest factor can we  do better than them?

Comment: As $2n + 1$ can be prime, there might not always exist such $a$. Otherwise it's equivalent to factorization, as mentioned above. Finding the smallest factor is the same difficulty (up to a polynomial factor) as full factorization, as one can divide out the smallest factor and repeat.

Comment: @Sil In general, yes, this is the best. But if the second largest prime factor is "small" , ECM is usually faster. The point is that there are much better methods than trial division , but still factoring is considered to be hard.